# Is it advisable to formally compare (e.g. with a test) the odds ratios from logistic regressions in 2 different survey years?

Tags: regression, logistic, survey, odds-ratio

I'm doing an analysis of several years of a large survey, regressing an $outcome$ on some predictors $P_1$, $P_2$, $\dots$ $P_n$ using logistic regression in each year. My study design is a bunch of repeated cross-sectional analyses, so I'm running the same model, on the same variables, in each year, and seeing what happens to the odds ratios the model spits out. To motivate the example, let's say that the $outcome$ is a binary $Has Lung Cancer$, and the predictors are things like $smoking$, $atherosclerosis$, $age$, and the like.

I know this question's somewhat squishy, but does it add anything to my analysis to *formally* compare the odds of lung cancer across levels of $P_1$ in different survey years in some way? Is there even such a way? To me, it's compelling enough to be able to say "hey, look at how the odds of lung cancer in smokers rose from $Year_1$ to $Year_2$ in survey respondents!" (obviously I'm reporting CIs, too, in this scenario), but is it advisable or "good statistical practice" (ambiguous phrases, I know) to use some test to formally say these ORs are different? Sure, what's advisable may change from person to person, but I'd like to hear any and all views on this.

I'm asking as similar question as [this person](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32646/method-to-compare-2-models-of-different-years-not-by-a-dummy-variable?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C46.6464) in some ways, but I'm not really following the answer.